# AVAudioEngine streaming audio from remote url

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation

Is it possible to use AVAudioEngine to stream audio from remote url? I see that I can create `AVAudioPCMBuffer` and then schedule it on `AVAudioPlayerNode`, but how can I fill `AVAudioPCMBuffer` with data from stream?

Comment: Even I have same question. Did you find any solution for that if yes please share.